# Is virtual host configuration and enabling sites necessary with lamp stack on ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

In windows with 'Wamp Server' installed, to create a new project for development I just create a new directory in 'www' (e.g. www/myproject) and access it with `http://localhost/myproject`.

But recently installed ubuntu,installed lamp stack by following tutorials on internet,  and found that things were not that easy.

I had to create a new myproject.conf file for every new project and then enable it then restart apache service.

Any easier/better alternate?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualHosts are only necessary, and will even only work, if you want to be able to access all your different projects using a different (sub)domain. For example:

```
mycoolproject.conf -> http://mycoolproject.com/
myotherproject.conf -> http://myotherproject.io/
```

If you are fine being able to access them using http://localhost/mycoolproject/ and http://localhost/myotherproject/, you do not need seperate `.conf` files.

Creating seperate `.conf` files all using `http://localhost` as their domain, will probably not work.

Comment: can you please suggest me how do i create and access my projects in www folder.. because the server can't find my projects

Comment: This should work the same way it does on Windows. LAMP should come with a default preinstalled configuration, the one used when you browse to ```http://localhost```, find that configuration file and put all your projects in the folder that is used in that configuration file.